# Can I count occurrence in 1 loop in this Scala fragment?

Tags: scala

I have a simple piece of Scala code. I loop sequentially through a List of Strings, and I want to count the occurrence of each String which I collect as tuples (String, Int) in the list r. The part in the main function should remain (so no `groupBy` or something). My question is about the update function:

right now I do a `find` first, and then add a new tuple to r if it doesn't exist. If it does exist, I loop through r and update the counter for the matching String.

Can the update function be modified so that it is more efficient? Can r be updated in a single iteration (adding if it doesn't exist, updating the counter if it does exist)?

Thanks

```
var r = List[(String, Int)]() // (string, count)

def update(s: String, l: List[(String, Int)]) : List[(String, Int)] = {
  if (r.find(a => a._1  == s) == None) {
    (s, 1) :: r // add a new item if it does not exist
  } else {
    for (b <- l) yield {
      if (b._1 == s) {
        (b._1, b._2 + 1) // update counter if exists
      } else {
        b // just yield if no match
      }
    }
  }
}

def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
  val l = "A" :: "B" :: "A" :: "C" :: "A" :: "B" :: Nil

  for (s <- l) r = update(s, r)

  r foreach println
}
```

Comment: I do not understand exactly what your objection to `groupBy` is. It seems to say that the code in the `main` definition may not be changed by the solution; It might also mean that `l` may not be changed. So, could you please clarify?

Comment: mainly because I also want to work with lazy collections. Or can you also use `groupBy` for lazy collections and `Streams` (or `Source.getLines`)? If so, please give me an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use groupBy or work with lazy collections (Streams), this could be the way to go:

```
ss.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]())((m, s) => m + (s -> (m.getOrElse(s, 0) + 1)))
```

Comment: That does return a `Map` instead of a `List`, though, and is not a stand-in replacement for `update` (even though I see @JanWillem has accepted your answer :).

Comment: That's true, return type is different, but it does comply with the goal I want to reach: "...I want to count the occurrence of each String..."

Answer (score 22):

I suggest you go for the functional style and use the power of Scala's collections:

```
ss.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

Comment: `s => s` is predefined as `identity`

Comment: This solution comes up so often, it really should go in the core library.  I'd call the method `tally`.

Comment: I agree, this is a good solution, but I was looking for an alternative for `groupBy`, also to be used with lazy collections, so therefore I selected the other answer by Heiko.

Comment: I keep an implementation of this as a standard pimp of Traversable that I pretty much include in all my projects.  I call it "countBy" and also have handy methods "sumBy", "minBy", "maxBy" and similar.  Between them, they cover a lot of my data reduction needs.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this also works:

```
val l = List("A","B","A","C","A","B")

l.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]()) {
  case (a: Map[String, Int], s: String) => {
    a + (s -> (1 + a.getOrElse(s, 0)))
  }
}

res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map((A,3), (B,2), (C,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your present solution is horribly slow, mainly because of the choice of `r` as a `List`. But your iteration throughout the whole list in case of update can be improved on, at least. I'd write it like this

```
def update(s: String, l: List[(String, Int)]) : List[(String, Int)] = {
  l span (_._1 != s) match {
    case (before, (`s`, count) :: after) => before ::: (s, count + 1) :: after
    case _ => (s, 1) :: l
  }
}
```

Using `span` avoids having to search the list twice. Also, we just append `after`, without having to iterate through it again.